# Converting user to systemd-homed user: sudo is not recognized

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, sudo, manjaro

I have converted an existing user to systemd-homed following [this](https://systemd.io/CONVERTING_TO_HOMED/) article. I have added the converted user to the wheel group using the "member-of=wheel" as described in the [homectl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/homectl.html) manual.

The group appears in the .identity file of the converted user. However, trying to execute a command as sudo does not work (keeps telling me that my password is wrong).

I have checked the members of the wheel group as well using "getent" and the user does not appear, which, if I am not mistaken, was expected since the systemd-homed user is removed from the usual system databases (/etc/passwd).

I have checked the /etc/pam.d/sudo file. Here is the content of the file

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth required pam_env.so
auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
auth required pam_deny.so
auth            include         system-auth
account         include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
```

Removing the line "auth required pam_deny.so" solves the issue.

However, I do not necessarily feel confident enough to perform the above change. What is going on here? What are the consequences of removing the above line from /etc/pam.d/sudo? Why does this solve my problem?

I would highly appreciate your help. Thank you very much in advance.

**System information**

Linux Manjaro 21.1.1 with Gnome 40.4.0 (according to /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml)

My nsswitch.conf file looks as follows

```
# Name Service Switch configuration file.
# See nsswitch.conf(5) for details.

passwd: files mymachines systemd
group: files [SUCCESS=merge] mymachines systemd
shadow: files systemd

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns   mdns4 myhostname
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files
```

My /etc/pam.d/system-auth looks as follows

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required                    pam_faillock.so      preauth
# Optionally use requisite above if you do not want to prompt for the password
# on locked accounts.
auth       [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so          try_first_pass nullok
-auth      [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_systemd_home.so
auth       [default=die]               pam_faillock.so      authfail
auth       optional                    pam_permit.so
auth       required                    pam_env.so
auth       required                    pam_faillock.so      authsucc
# If you drop the above call to pam_faillock.so the lock will be done also
# on non-consecutive authentication failures.

-account   [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_systemd_home.so
account    required                    pam_unix.so
account    optional                    pam_permit.so
account    required                    pam_time.so

-password  [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_systemd_home.so
password   required                    pam_unix.so          try_first_pass nullok shadow sha512
password   optional                    pam_permit.so

session    required                    pam_limits.so
session    required                    pam_unix.so
session    optional                    pam_permit.so
```

Comment: I don't have Arch and I've never used `systemd-homed` so I'm not comfortable writing this up as an answer. However, it looks like you're missing the [configuration under `/etc/pamd.d`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pam_systemd_home.8#EXAMPLE) that pulls in the extra group from `systemd-homed`. In turn this means that `sudo` can't see the user in in the `wheel` group. Or if that's included, you need to reorganise the order of the entries, because you'd be denying before checking with `system-auth`

Comment: @roaima Thank you very much for your quick response and you might be right. However, the configuration from the link is exactly the configuration in my system-auth which is also located in /etc/pamd.d. The sudo file shouldn't be modified or at least it is not mentioned in the documentation. I also tested changing the order of the entries with no success. The only thing that solved it was removing the line "auth required pam_deny.so", which might bypasses the wheel group (but I don't know for sure what is going on here).

Comment: Can you add `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` to your question please

Comment: I have added the system-auth to my question.